How to fix old PC with black screen, POST code 00h, and no beeps after CMOS battery replacement and BIOS flash?
I’m facing a serious issue with my old PC featuring an APC Raptor AT-11/04/03 motherboard and AMIBIOS from American Megatrends (1997). I was getting a "low CMOS battery" error, so I soldered a new lithium battery onto the Benchmarq bq3287AMT RTC module (reference video).
After powering on the PC, I encountered a black screen, continuous single beeps every second, and a POST code of 33h. According to the documentation, this means the BIOS couldn’t find the AMIBOOT.ROM file in the root directory of floppy drive
A. The keyboard also stopped working.
I attempted to flash the BIOS using a floppy disk with the latest version I found online. Unfortunately, things got worse—now there’s no POST, no beeps, just a black screen, and a POST code of 00h, which indicates: "Code copying to specific areas is done. Passing control to INT 19h boot loader next."
I’ve already tried the following steps without success:
Replacing and reseating the 128MB RAM (cleaned with an eraser).
Resetting the CMOS using jumpers.
Using a different monitor.
Removing all external cards and peripherals.
Reflashing the BIOS.

I’d appreciate any advice on how to recover the system or troubleshoot further.

If he has a failed bios flash on a machine from that period, it's likely a dumpster candidate

How long did you wait? Flashing takes some time.

Anything new enough to have a built in post card might be new enough to have a socketed BIOS.  There used to be people who could sell you a flashed replacement.  Also I've seen a screen of the ATX board by the same name and it's got one of those Dallas clock-blocks which often have an integrated battery.  So maybe check that too.

Have you tried using one of the backdoor BIOS passwords?  It's possible that one of your steps accidentally set the BIOS password to something random.

POST doesn’t really tell you what went wrong. What it really tells you is, what was the last thing that went right. E.g., 33h really means that every thing that it does before looking for AMIBOOT.ROM worked. 00h means only that resetting the POST counter to zero worked. It probably doesn't even need a CPU present to get to 00h.

So, would purchasing a new BIOS chip solve the issue, or would the entire motherboard need to be replaced?
For reference, this is the website where I downloaded the updated firmware version for my motherboard BIOS version is RBXAT-09 (Raptor AT), dated 11/04/03:
https://theretroweb.com/motherboards/s/apc-raptor-at
